# Angular 6 load css folders in angular.json

Tags: css, angular6

I am trying to convert my html template into angular app. I have a css folder called plugins and img folder.

When I am adding :

```
 "styles": [
          "src/assets/plugins/listtyicons/style.css",
          "src/assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css",
          "src/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/assets/plugins/plugins/isotope/isotope.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"

        ]
```

this code in angular.json file I am getting error when trying to start angular app. I have put my plugin folder inside assets folder. I am getting this error:

```
 ERROR in multi ./src/assets/plugins/listtyicons/style.css 
./src/assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css ./src/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css ./src/assets/plugins/plugins/isotope/isotope.min.css ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
'/Users/nilay/angular/bes/src/assets/plugins/plugins/isotope/isotope.min.css' 
in '/Users/nilay/angular/bes'
```

I don't know why am I getting this error.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In **angular 6** you have to add **only** in `src/style.css` (instead `angular.json`):

```
@import "assets/plugins/listtyicons/style.css";
@import "assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css";
@import "assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import  "assets/plugins/plugins/isotope/isotope.min.css";
```

And in  `angular.json`

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ]
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Where are the docs on this? Can you point me to them, please?

Comment: `plugin` is folder that the user create... but if you npm bootstrap , jquery the files in node.modukes folder

Comment: @לבנימלכה - could you please tell, how to include JS files?

Comment: like style you have "scripts" arr put there those links

Comment: Thanks, I was going crazy with this!