# Angular 6 - Less CSS' import is not working anymore

Tags: javascript, css, angular, less

I wanted to re-use some structure from an Angular 5 project which uses Less. In this old project I could simply load `.less` files using this line from within a component:

```
@import '~app/shared/less/bootstrap';
```

This would load:

```
/my-app/src/app/shared/less/bootstrap.less
```

---

Now I have a blank Angular 6 project, which is also configured to use Less as a preprocessor:

```
ng new my-app --routing --style less
```

**Extract from `angular.json`**:

```
"my-app": {
  "prefix": "app",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "less"
    }
  },
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "options": {
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.less",
          "app/shared/less/styles.less"
```

---

However the line

```
@import '~app/shared/less/bootstrap';
```

… compiles with an error:

> Failed to compile.
>   ./src/app/shared/component/some.component.less
>   Module build failed:
>   @import '~app/shared/less/bootstrap';
>    ^
>   '~app/shared/less/bootstrap' wasn't found.

I also tried:

```
@import '.app/shared/less/bootstrap';
@import '.src/app/shared/less/bootstrap';
@import '~app/shared/less/bootstrap.less';
```

… without any luck.

Did I forget to configue something?

Comment: try to add extantion to you imports(like `.js`, `.css`) `@import '.app/shared/less/bootstrap.less';`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @לבנימלכה. As mentioned in the quesiton - I already tried it without any luck, unfortunately.

Comment: see my answer please

Comment: use `/` before app : @import './app/shared/less/bootstrap.less'

Comment: @לבנימלכה Your idea was close. I got it working using the fully qualified path  `@import './src/app/` -  including `./` and `src`. Thanks. Would you add this to your answer?

Comment: i edited really appricate if you up vote and mark as answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In angular 6 you have to `import` all files to main(in your case `src/styles.less`) css file :

**In `angular.json` put ONLY:**

```
  "styles": [
          "src/styles.less"
]
```

**In `styles.less` (import all files you want with `/` before `app`):**

```
@import './app/shared/less/bootstrap.less';
```

See my answer to css here:[Angular 6 load css folders in angular.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50617488/angular-6-load-css-folders-in-angular-json/50617680#50617680)

**To your edit `./src/app..`:**

```
@import './src/app/...'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Is there a way, when importing all mixins and variables into the file linked in `angular.json` to make them available in components as well? So that the import of mixins and variables in every single componentn wouldn't be necessary anymore? Unfortunatley `stylePreprocessorOptions` works only with SASS.