# Less CSS import stopped working in Angular 7 - how to fix it?

Tags: angular, import, less, angular7

In Angular 5 I imported a `bootstrap.less` into any less file of a component using:

```
@import '~app/shared/less/bootstrap';
```

In [Angular 6 I updated this to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51041765/2711071):

```
@import './src/app/shared/less/bootstrap';
```

Now with Angular 7 it has stopped again:

> Can't resolve './src/app/shared/less/bootstrap' …

---

Basically I have a Less CSS file with some mixins and variables that is loccted in `/src/app/shared/less/`. I wanto to use this file in any component's Less CSS file and must therefor import it, to acces the included mixins.

---

What is the corect syntax in Angular 7?

Comment: in angular 7 you can use  `~src`

Comment: @nircraft Thanks, that helped a lot. Could you add this as an answer? Also, do you know why they changed it and what the tilde does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `~src/app/shared/less/bootstrap` to import bootstrap or use a relative path for importing ex: `../../shared/less/bootstrap` (depending on your project structure).

`~` is a quick way to reference root in order to operate paths to SCSS/LESS.

The usage of the `tilde` was/is **NOT** [officially supported](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10077#issuecomment-399772664) and is actual an artifact of the internal implementation of the build system.

While it may currently work in certain situations, it is not guaranteed to continue to function in the future. In the style use cases outlined above, a relative path or the use of the `includePaths` option ([more details](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles)) is recommended.