# How to share a css root constant to another css file?

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to use the same colors again and again in my Angular test project. So, I made a constants.css where I declare my root constants which are all colors at the moment. However I'm stuck at trying to use them in my individual components' css files.

I tried to include constants.css at the html file and doesn't work. I tried both @import url("constants.css") and @import "constants.css".

constants.css

```css
:root {
    --primary-color: #2c3e50;
    --secondary-color: #f1c40f;
    --background-color: #ecf0f1;
    --accent-color: #c0392b;
}
```

nav.component.css

```css
@import url("../../../constants.css");

a.logo {
    color: var(--secondary-color);
}
```

I expected my logo text to be yellow but it's just default black.

Comment: Your code seems ok. It must be a problem with your location of file.Are you sure that the path is right?

Comment: Pretty sure the path is right as the IDE helps. But I'll try repositioning. Thanks man.

Comment: Welcome. Try that. because I just copied your code and tested it and it worked well.

Comment: I just found out man, it's Angular thing. I have to import it to the main style.css. not individual css files.

Answer (score 5):

You've forget to declare your variable in your css file where you want to use global variable:

```
@value --secondary-color from "here should be your address";

a.logo {
    color: var(--secondary-color);
}
```

Let me show an example:

shared.css:

```
:root {
    --primary-color: #2c3e50;
    --secondary-color: #f1c40f;
    --background-color: #ecf0f1;
    --accent-color: #c0392b;
}
```

and in `main.css` you should write `@value --secondary-color` like this

```
@value --secondary-color from "./shared.css";

.background {
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}
```

And do not forget to include your `css` files:

```
<link href="shared.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Do not forget that order of declaration of stylesheets does matter.

Comment: I just found out man, it's Angular thing. I have to import it to the main style.css. not individual css files. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

My problem has been the import not working at all because it's Angular thing. I have to import my constant into the main style.css and importing in individual css files doesn't work at all.

The right answer of this link is the answer.

[Angular 6 - Less CSS' import is not working anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041765/angular-6-less-css-import-is-not-working-anymore)